# Why are the tests of the response not failing in Rider http-client?

Tags: javascript, jetbrains-ide, rider, web-api-testing, intellij-http-client

A webservice returns this json

```json
{
  "title": "Test how to filter the response",
  "features": [
    { "feature": "AB1", "price": "1.00"},
    { "feature": "AB1", "price": "1.23"},
    { "feature": "CD2", "price": "2.00"},
    { "feature": "EF3", "price": "3.00"},
    { "feature": "GH4", "price": "4.00"}
  ]
}
```

With [intellij-http-client](/questions/tagged/intellij-http-client) or in my case the [jetbrains-rider](/questions/tagged/jetbrains-rider)-implementation of http-client the following code should

- test that `AB1` was only 1 time present (expected = 1, actual = 2)
- test that the price of `AB1` is `0.00` (expected) and not something else (actual = `1.00` and `1.23`)

```js
> {%
     
    // this should fail since 2 AB1-features were sent
    client.test("feature AB1 was sent 1 time", function() {
        var features = response.body.features;         
        const result = features.filter(obj => obj.feature === "AB1");
        result.forEach(r => client.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
        client.assert(result.length, "1"); 
    });
    
    // should fail since the price is not 0
    client.test("feature AB1 price is 0.00", function() {
        var features = response.body.features;              
        const result = features.filter(obj => obj.feature === "AB1");
        client.assert(result[0].price, "0.00");  
        client.log("price of " + result[0].feature + " = " + result[0].price); 
        
    });     
%}
```

But the above code used in [rider](/questions/tagged/rider) has not the result i expected

[image: JetBrains_Rider_http-client]

#### Question

- Why are the tests not failing?
- Where is the flaw / mistake in my code?

Comment: There is now an issue [see RIDER-85248](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-85248/http-client-test-assert-expected-fail-but-actual-pass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a wrong use of the [http-client API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-reference.html#client-methods): `client.assert(assertion, [message])` where the assertion must be a boolean expression. The message is optional.

```js
// must contain an expression that returns a boolean
client.assert(result.length == "1")
```